# Forcing Overflow menu button on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am developing an application for Android 4.0.3. I have multiple fragments and I have one menu item displayed on each of them. I want to have an overflow menu button that will have 2 menu items. How do I force the appearance of the overflow menu and add menu items to it ? I am adding menu items by calling the onCreateOptionsMenu function in each fragment.

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What specifically is the problem that you are encountering?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to force the display of the overflow menu button.

Comment: Not all devices will show a button on-screen. Devices or emulators with a dedicated MENU button use that instead of an on-screen button, as that is what the users of those devices will be used to.

Comment: UPDATE: As of KitKat (4.4), devices will show an overflow button on screen whether or not they have a physical menu button.  Of course, that doesn't help for earlier Android versions, but, FYI, it is at least a fun fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To force into the overflow menu do this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
   menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Item 1").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

   return true;
}
```

`SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW` will force the item into either:

Android 3.0 +  :  The ActionBar as an overflow
Android 2.3 -  :  The menu button

If you are wanting to recreate the menu you will need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` This will re-create from `OnCreateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: I have already tried that and it didn't work. An overflow menu button wasn't seen on the emulator.

Comment: I made an edit to my original question and I have added my code so you could see what I am exactly doing. After adding the above code you mentioned I still am not able to force the display of the overflow menu.

Comment: Commonsware is right. The emulator doesn't show the overflow button, but my tablet did. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You tablet probably shows the overflow button because it does not have a physical menu button.