# Android - how to specify the width to menu items in actionbar for displaying the menu items in Over flow button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have implemented an action bar for displaying the menu items. 
So I have given   `android:showAsAction="always"` for 3 menu items and `android:showAsAction="withtext"` for other 4 menu items which I want to display inside an over-flow menu.

But these items are displaying in menu panel when i run the code in devices running android below 3.0 versions. Sometimes these are displaying the action bar also if i run the code in large screen display devices. 
How can i restrict the width for menu items to adjust in all screen resolutions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display certain items inside overflow menu , use `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to those particular menu items in your menu.xml.

Note that if the target device is having a dedicated/hard menu button you will not be able to see the overflow button inside action bar as per the docs.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851462/forcing-overflow-menu-button-on-android) will also help you..

**EDIT**

This will provide you with an overflow menu if device doesn't have hard button . 
If you want to show the overflow menu even if you have the hard button try following :

```
try {
      ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
                if(menuKeyField != null) {
                    menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                    menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Ignore
            }
```

Its a little hack which will force the device to ignore the hard menu button.

Check out the following code. This implementation will show Item 4 only in the action bar and others inside the overflow menu. This happens because its the only one which has been provided with Show_As_Always.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
       menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Item 1").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
       menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Item 2").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
       menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Item 3").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
       menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Item 4").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
       menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Item 5").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

       return true;
    }
```

Comment: yes in below 3.0 the same menu items are displaying in menu panel what ever the items i have mentioned as with text. but they are not coming as i expect. if i mentioned ifroom they will come in the menu panel if  the suffiecient space is available. but i want the items in overflow button (for above 3.0) and in more button (for below 3.0) if the sufficient space avialb;e also

Comment: Still those items coming in menu panel only @purushotham

Comment: did you tried the another snippet provided in Edit section..?

Comment: yes i already using that for displaying the over flow button explicitly. i have mentioned 4 items as with text for showing in overflow button. but 2 of then has taken the menu panel space because space is there. but i want them in overflow only

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add programmatically, use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Item #1").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
    menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Item #2").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
    return true;
}
```

Also you can add items via menu XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/your_id_1"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Item #1"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/your_id_2"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Item #2"/>

</menu>
```